# How to compare two data frame and get the unmatched rows using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, rows

I have two data frames, df1 and df2. Now, df1 contains 6 records and df2 contains 4 records. I want to get the unmatched records out of it. I tried it but getting an error `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labelled DataFrame objects` I guess this is due to the length of df as the df1 has 6 and df2 has 4 but how do I compare them both and get the unmatched rows?

code

```
df1=
  a  b  c
0 1  2  3
1 4  5  6
2 3  5  5
3 5  6  7
4 6  7  8
5 6  6  6


df2 =
  a  b  c
0 3  5  5
1 5  6  7
2 6  7  8
3 6  6  6

index = (df != df2).any(axis=1)
df3 = df.loc[index]
```

which gives:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labelled DataFrame objects
```

Expected output:

```
 a  b  c
0 1  2  3
1 4  5  6
```

I know that the error is due to the length but is there any way where we can compare two data frames and get the unmatched records out of it?

Comment: One of logic can be that check each row in both. And then take using `np.setdiff1d` we will take set diff.

`np.setdiff1d([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[np.where(np.all(df1==df2.iloc[x],axis=1))[0][0] for x in range(4)])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `MultiIndex.from_frame` + `isin`

We can use `MultiIndex.from_frame` on both `df1` and `df2` to create the corresponding multiindices, then use `isin` to test the membership of the index created from `df1` in `index` created from `df2` to create a boolean mask which can be then used to filter the non matching rows.

```
i1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1)
i2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df2)
df1[~i1.isin(i2)]
```

#### Result

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True` and pick all rows except `both`:

```
In [173]: df = df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='outer').query('_merge != "both"').drop('_merge', 1)

In [174]: df
Out[174]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```